# get RGB-YCbCr components of image

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg, rgb

I want to show the jpeg image   R_G_B channels as separated images in jlabel and the Y-Cb-Cr channels as well, I got the arrays but don't know how to convert them to images
///

Edit:
thanX very much , this is the method I'm writing ,Now It can display just the upper left quarter of the image ,and show it in a blue color whatever the color channel was?

```
      public void getRGB_YCC(int width,int height,String inFileName) {
            R=new int[height][width];G=new int[height][width];
            B=new int[height][width];Y=new int[height][width];
            Cb1=new int[height][width];Cr1=new int[height][width];
            final int values[] = new int[width * height];
            int r, g, b, Y_ch,Cb,Cr, y, x;

            final PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(image.getSource(), 0, 0,width,height, values, 0, width);

                try {
                if (grabber.grabPixels() != true) {
                try {
                throw new AWTException("Grabber returned false: " + grabber.getStatus());
                } catch (final Exception e) {};
                }
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {};
                int index = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                r = values[index] >> 16 & 0xff;
                g = values[index] >> 8 & 0xff;
                b = values[index] & 0xff;

                Y_ch= (int)(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b);
                Cb= 128 + (int) (-0.16874 * r - 0.33126 * g + 0.5 * b);
                Cr= 128 + (int)(0.5 * r - 0.41869 * g - 0.08131 * b);
                R [y][x]=r;
                G [y][x]=g;
                B [y][x]=b;
                Y [y][x]=Y_ch; 
                Cb1[y][x]=Cb; 
                Cr1[y][x]=Cr;
                index++;
                }
        }
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    for(  y=0;y<height;y++)
    {
    for(  x=0;x<width;x++)
    {
        pixels[x + y*width] =R[y][x]<<16;
    }
    }

     jLabel15.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fast way to get an array of pixels into an image is using [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html):

This example creates a grayscale 8 bit image and retrieves a 'pixel buffer' for it:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

This also works with RGB:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

You now can set pixels by just writing to the `pixels` array like `pixels[x + y * w] = value` and the results are instantly visible.

Comment: I used this code but there is an exception" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"
what's wrong ?

  BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

 int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

for(  y=0;y<height;y++)
{
for(  x=0;x<width;x++)
{
    pixels[x + y * width] =R[y][x];
}
}
 WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) img.getData();

 raster.setPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels); 
     
 jLabel15.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

Comment: First, without more information I really can't answer you question (in which line of the above code gets the exception thrown?), and second: You do not need to do any `raster.setPixel` or other stuff, as I said: ... and the results are instantly visible. You do work directly on the buffered image data.

Comment: You write to an `INT_RGB` buffered image, so you have three color channels inside yout integer: `0xrrggbb`. Currently you write values between 0 and 255 in the blue channel only. To get different colors, shift the value.

Comment: I really really thank you,but still one quarter of the image is shown
and doesn't show the whole image ,I don't know why?
|
to show YCbCr  channels,could   TYPE_INT_RGB work ?

Comment: Can anybody tell me what's wrong I'm doing,so that the whole image couldn't be shown ,and show just part of it????????????

Comment: don't worry , I've got it, the mistake was in the parameters I passing them to the method ,thankX So much

Comment: Great, as the code didn't contain any obvious errors I was hoping that it was about the input parameters.